# Error when trying to remove node from parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

This code is in an if statement that checks if the user touches a correct button. If not returned true this code below will run. The problem is that when  `live` is removed from parent the line `let live = childNodeWithName("liveBall") as! SKSpriteNode` returns this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value.

This must be because `childNodeWithName("liveBall")` does no longer exist.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let live = SKSpriteNode(texture: purpleTexture)
    live.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.68, self.frame.size.height * 0.93)
    live4.name = "liveBall"
    self.addChild(live)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let live = childNodeWithName("liveBall") as! SKSpriteNode
    if(intersectsNode(live)){
        live.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no "liveBall" node as a child. Are you sure it is added? It seems that there is a typo (number 4) in:

```
live4.name = "liveBall"
```

You can try to add node like that:

```
var mySprite: SKSpriteNode = childNodeWithName("mySprite") as SKSpriteNode
```

Answer (score 0):

To add safety to your function that calls `RemoveFromParent()`, simply add a new Boolean variable that changes itself to true when `RemoveFromParent()` is called and use a condition check to prevent it from occuring twice.